# Twing e Controller na symfony

Tags: php, aplicação-web, symfony-2

Tenho um formulário feito na twing e quero passar os valores desse formulário para o meu banco de dados e para isso tenho que mandar para o controller, não?

Answer (score 0):

O Symfony tem uma forma "particular" para trabalhar com formulários.

Basicamente ele é construído no Controller e e depois precisa ser iniciado no Twig.

Segue um passo a passo:

1° Crie uma entidade para representar os campos de seu formulário. Caso você já tenha um objeto para persistir estes dados basta instanciá-lo.

2° Crie o formulário com os campos que você deseja retorno.

3° Inicie e manipule o form conforme sua vontade no Twig.

Na documentação existe um exemplo muito claro de como você pode fazer isso:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html